# SQL script for joining two tables and only showing results with the most recent timestamp?

Tags: sql, join, left-join, cockroachdb

Suppose I am a bank:

I have a table with a set of user identities called `user_identity`, and another `user_balance` with a list of every balance a user has ever had.

A new entry is created in `user_balance` every time a user deposits or withdraws money from their account. Each entry has the following fields:

1. `timestamp` - the date of the recorded balance
2. `id` - unique identifier
3. `userId` - id of the user who owns the account
4. `amountCents` - dollar amount in cents of the balance
5. `relatedTransferId` - unique identifier of the withdrawal or deposit that led there to be a new balance created
6. `previousBalanceId` - unique identifier of the balance that came before it

I want to write two scripts:

1. One that returns the sum of all the money currently stored across all accounts
2. One that returns a list of all users and their current balance

Here is my attempt at writing the second one:

```
SELECT 
    user_balance."amountCents" * (1/100) AS balance, 
    "user"."identityId",
    user_identity."firstName",
    user_identity."lastName",
    user_balance.timestamp
FROM user_balance
JOIN user_identity
    ON user_identity.id = user_balance."userId"
ORDER BY 1;
```

I don't know how to select only the most recent balance for a given user. Any and all help would be very appreciated!

`user_balance` sample table (notice how there may be more than one entry per user id because there is an entry for each time the balance changes!):

```
            timestamp           |     userId      | amountCents
--------------------------------+-----------------+--------------
  2021-05-12 07:02:05.088+00:00 | u_2przr9gcn52sm |       20607
  2021-05-12 17:08:05.552+00:00 | u_ysvzqzs7f862  |           0
  2021-05-19 00:40:29.62+00:00  | u_y9eyf0j3b5i5  |      407454
  2021-05-16 21:47:34.123+00:00 | u_jze8wwmuuudk  |       66500
  2021-05-14 08:01:03.929+00:00 | u_22cyb1sctel5k |     3881602
  2021-05-17 05:01:02.711+00:00 | u_22cyb1sctel5k |     3435703
```

`user_identity` sample table:

```
         id        |         firstName          |      lastName
-------------------+----------------------------+----------------------
  ui_104xy9vczsrmy | John                       | Doe
  ui_10holeidg2ydt | John                       | Doe
  ui_10no0d6mtvdfi | John                       | Doe
```

Desired result:

```
      firstName    |         lastName           |      currentBalance
-------------------+----------------------------+----------------------
  John             | Doe                        | 3000
  John             | Doe                        | 2000
  John             | Doe                        | 1000
```

(where `currentBalance` in the final table is the balance associated with the most recent timestamp inside the `user_balance` table).

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: Hey @TheImpaler! Added rows of sample data and expected result. Your help is much appreciated

Comment: Maybe `ORDER BY 1` –> `ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1`?

Comment: @JoshuaR. I think that would only return 1 result?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` on a table expression to identify the rows you want and exclude the other ones.

For example:

```
select
  i.firstName,
  i.lastName,
  x.amountCents as currentBalance
from user_identity i
left join (
  select b.*,
    row_number() over(partition by b.userId 
                      order by b.timestamp desc) as rn
  from user_balance b
) x on x.id = i.userId
where x.rn = 1
```